# Using Placed with Show - the simplest solution to move the legend around?

Tags: plotting, legending

Please let me know if this is a duplicate. There are some solutions, but I think there must be something simpler for this kind of situation.

```
ListLinePlot[{1, 2, 3}, PlotLegends -> Placed[{"graph1"}, {0.8, 0.5}]]
```

produces a legend placed as I would like to:

[image]

If I have several plots, I can use show and duplicate the above:

```
Show[
 ListLinePlot[{1, 2, 3}, PlotLegends -> Placed[{"graph1"}, {0.8, 0.5}], PlotStyle -> Red],
 Plot[x^2, {x, 1, 3}, PlotLegends -> Placed[{"graph2"}, {0.8, 0.5}],   PlotStyle -> Blue]
 ]
```

[image]

As I cannot use `Plotlegends` with `Show`, what to do to make the code simpler and not to use the commands repeatedly? I know that perhaps `ShowLegend` could help... I will have about 10 lines in my final plot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Legended[Show[ListLinePlot[{1, 2, 3}, PlotStyle->Red], 
   Plot[x^2, {x, 1, 3}, PlotStyle->Blue]], 
 Placed[LineLegend[{Red, Blue}, {"graph1", "graph2"}], {0.8, 0.5}]]
```

[image]

Or, use a function to pass the styles into the plots in `Show` and into `LineLegend`:

```
Legended[Show[ListLinePlot[{1, 2, 3}, PlotStyle -> #], 
    Plot[x^2, {x, 1, 3}, PlotStyle -> #2]], 
   Placed[LineLegend[{##}, {"graph1", "graph2"}], {0.8, 0.5}]] & @@ {Red, Blue}
(* same picture *)
```

Or, collect the colors as they are specified into the list `colors` and use use `colors` as the first argument of `LineLegend`:

```
colors = {}; 
Legended[ Show[ListLinePlot[{1, 2, 3}, PlotStyle -> (AppendTo[colors, Red]; Red)], 
  Plot[x^2, {x, 1, 3}, PlotStyle -> (AppendTo[colors, Blue]; Blue)]], 
 Placed[LineLegend[colors, {"graph1", "graph2"}], {0.8, 0.5}]]
(* same picture *)
```

Or, use `Reap/Sow`:

```
Legended[reap = 
  Reap[Show[ListLinePlot[{1, 2, 3}, PlotStyle -> Sow[Red]], 
    Plot[x^2, {x, 1, 3}, PlotStyle -> Sow[Blue]]]]; reap[[1]], 
 Placed[LineLegend[reap[[2, 1]], {"graph1", "graph2"}], {0.8, 0.5}]]
(* same picture *)
```

Or, use a prespecified color list:

```
cols="DefaultPlotStyle"/.(Method/.Charting`ResolvePlotTheme["Vibrant", ListLinePlot] );

Legended[ Show[ListLinePlot[{1, 2, 3}, PlotStyle -> cols[[1]]], 
  Plot[x^2, {x, 1, 3}, PlotStyle ->  cols[[2]]]], 
 Placed[LineLegend[cols, {"graph1", "graph2"}], {0.8, 0.5}]]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Thank you, this works But how about if I wanted the line style of the graph (e.g. color) to be automatically transferred to the legend? So as not to mix up the graphs, if there are more of them.

Comment: @wondering, please see the updated post with some ways to collect the color information to be used in `LineLegend`.  I don't know of a  way to automatically extract `PlotStyle` information of  a graphics object once it is rendered.

Comment: Thank you. But would you have an idea how to specify here one of the color schemes (Automatic, "Classic","Vibrant","Monochrome"), instead of specifying the colors manually?

Comment: @wondering, just added an example showing how you can use a prespecified color list.

Comment: That is exactly it, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

To address your question after the answer of kguler. You might want to create functions that take care of that automatically, such as e.g.:

```
    myPlot[f_, xmin_, xmax_, pos_List, color_] := 
  Plot[f[x], {x, xmin, xmax}, PlotStyle -> color, 
   PlotLegends -> 
    Placed[LineLegend[{ToString[f] <> "[x]"}], Scaled[pos]]
   ];
myLLPlot[lst_List, pos_List, name_String, color_] := 
  ListLinePlot[lst, PlotStyle -> color, 
   PlotLegends -> Placed[PointLegend[{name}], Scaled[pos]]
   ];
```

Here pos is a list giving the scaled position of where the legend to appear, and color is the color of both the plot and the legend.

To give an example, let us plot the following together using Show:

```
    g[x_] := x^2;
lst = {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}};
```

This is done as follows:

```
    Show[
 myPlot[g, 0, 2, {0.8, 0.1}, Red],
 myLLPlot[lst, {0.8, 0.15}, "list", Blue]
        ]
```

yielding

[image]

On the other hand, I do not really see, what is the gain. Using Show one anyway needs to fix somehow the colors of the plots let alone their names in the legends. To my personal test I would rather use something like the following:

```
 Show[{
  ListLinePlot[lst, PlotStyle -> Blue
   ],

  Plot[g[x], {x, 0, 3}, PlotRange -> {{0, 3.5}, Automatic}, 
   PlotStyle -> Red]
  },
 (* The legends are in the Epilog starting here *)
 Epilog -> Inset[Panel[Column[{
      LineLegend[{Blue}, {"  Data"}],
      LineLegend[{Red}, {"g[x]"}]
      }]], Scaled[{0.8, 0.2}]]
 (* End of the Legends*)

 ]
```

giving this:

[image]

since the panel gives a more accurate view of the legend. Have fun!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It is indeed not trivial to fix colors using `Show`!